# Wordcloud with conditional font type

Tags: r, graph, rstudio, word-cloud

I'm looking to apply a world cloud function but change the font type formatting based on another column.

The idea is that I would like to have the font type (italic, plain, bold) of the words based on the 'status' column

```
df=read.table(text="name    freq    year status
paris   5       2010  OK
nyc     25      2010   OK
tokyo   10      2011   NOT
rome    9       2011   NOT",
header=TRUE)

font_vector = c(1,3)


wordcloud(words = df$name, freq = df$freq, min.freq = 1,scale = c(5, 2), font = font_vector[factor(df$status)] , 
          max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.1, 
          ordered.colors=TRUE,
          colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2")[factor(df$year)] )
```

The problem is that instead of having two cities (Paris & NYC) in italic and the other two (Tokyo & Rome) in plain, everything is shifted to italic. Anyone has any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Running your code, after requiring the wordcloud package, I got tokyo and rome in brown and NYC and paris in green.  Did you also want italics?

Comment: You are right, the font doesn't change.  Maybe this SO question will help as it introduces family as a parameter.  I tried ifelse after the font and after vfont (which is used in the manual).  No luck.

Comment: try looking for different wordcloud packages, it may have this feature

Comment: @TheBiro Thanks, haven't find anything yet unfortunately!

Comment: @lawyer thanks for looking into it, no more luck so far in solving this